# TextBox.Keypress doesn't respond to return key

Tags: c#, textbox, keydown

I have a form with various text boxes.  One text box is used for entering a floating point number, so I am using TextBox.KeyPress to process each digit in turn, which only modifies the Text property.  The text is processed by a routine that is called when the OK button id pressed (before closing the form).  It is also called by the TextBox.Leave event.  However, if I change the contents of the text box then press Return to variable isn't updated.

I thought I could overcome this by the following:

```
    private void DestPointNoTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
        {
            prvUpdateDestPointNo();
        }
    }
```

This is called whenever a key is pressed while the text box is in focus, as can be proved by setting a breakpoint within it.  However, it is not called when Return is pressed.

Can someone explain how I can ensure new text is processed when Return is pressed? 
 If I change the contents of one then click the OK button the new

Comment: Can you please show us the routine you are using to get the values ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows Form Application, then you can set the AcceptButton property of the Form to the OK button and the Click event of the OK button will be fired when you press Enter/Return key

Comment: What do you mean by `set the AcceptButton property to the OK button `.As far as i know there is no property named `AcceptButton` for `Button Control` although `TextBox Control` has a property named `AcceptsReturn`.And how you can call the `Click Event` of any Button with `Enter Key` unless it has keyboard focus ?

Comment: sorry, I mean the AcceptButton property on the Form.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Debugger to determine the value of `e.KeyCode` at runtime.

Why?

When I ran similar code (Winforms TextBox, KeyDown registered), the value of e.KeyCode was

```
e.KeyCode = LButton | MButton | Back
```

Another property of `KeyEventArgs` you can use is `KeyValue` -

```
private void DestPointNoTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyValue == 13)
    {
        prvUpdateDestPointNo();
    }
}
```